# QR Code not showing for 2 Factor authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to add in 2Factor authentication in my web application according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-enable-qrcodes?view=aspnetcore-3.0), however, the page is still not displaying the QR code and I cannot figure out what is wrong.

I am using .net core 3.1 entity framework core for the identity side of things and dapper for my dal.

This is my render scripts sections in the authentication page. The only thing i see that different is I am not modifying my app user class at all there no need for my app yet.

```
@section Scripts {
<partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/qrcode-generator/qrcode.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrCode"),
        {
            text: "@Html.Raw(Model.AuthenticatorUri)",
            width: 150,
            height: 150
        });
</script>

}
```

But If we look at my page on the manage section you will see the QR code still has not presented itself even though I adjusted the HTML to the following as requested.

```
 <li>
        <p>Scan the QR Code or enter this key <kbd>@Model.SharedKey</kbd> into your two factor authenticator app. Spaces and casing do not matter.</p>
        <div class="alert alert-info">To enable QR code generation please read our <a href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?Linkid=852423">documentation</a>.</div>
        <div id="qrCode"></div>
        <div id="qrCodeData" data-url="@Model.AuthenticatorUri"></div>
 </li>
```

My Startup Cs has the following in the configuration

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.Configure<ConnectionStringConfig>(Configuration);


  }
```

And there are no errors in the browser pertaining to the QR code I added the package using lib manager as directed for the QR code

[image]

U can see here my main View here

[image]

I hope that someone knows what done wrong I added the pages via the new scaffold item so they are in my account/manage folder as showing here

[image]

Also, how does one force login is there a way to enable 2fa at the registration stage or must they have an account to begin with.

I have also added all my tables using migrations to the database

[image]

Comment: I tried your code, but it works pretty fine for me. Is there a minimal demo that reproduces?

Comment: @itminus its working fine was an error in the path on my file system side. But the question was able to register the user using my Microsoft authentication app but unlike my work the profile icon was not blue was just a blank profile icon beside the code any ideas as to why. It issues the code ok and verified that it worked which was great.

Comment: @itminus revisiting this for another app , but  my 2fa icon is black how do i get it color blue like other applications for example microsoft outlook shows a blue sheild